# Inprivate filtering in IE disables itself

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I recentl discovered the built-in ad blocker in IE8, called inprivate filtering. It however disables itself on every IE start. How to enable it permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff758638.aspx) explains how.

> However, you can tweak the registry to keep the InPrivate Filtering feature on at all times by default. Open Registry Editor, navigate to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Safety\PrivacIE`, add the `DWORD` value `StartMode` (if it doesn’t already exist), and set its value to `1`. Internet Explorer will now retain and apply whatever decisions you made in the InPrivate Filtering Settings dialog box.

Comment: You probably meant 2. 1 causes IE to block all offsite content, which is not what I want (superuser will not work, for example).

Comment: @kinokijuf I was merely quoting the article. I have not tested it. It sounded exactly like what you want to do.